# ExifInterface got an unsupported image

Tags: android

I have used `ExifInterface` in an Android app for obtaining camera orientation  of an image. My code works perfectly for `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 24`. But when build version is greater or equal to 24 it gives warning in android studio logcat and does not work properly.

Here is my code block from onActivityResult method:

```
if(requestCode == REQUEST_CAPTURE_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Inside camera operation");
            int reqWidth = 480, reqHeight = 800;
            try {
                InputStream inStream = null;
                try {
                    inStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);

                    //Decode image size
                    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

                    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStream, null, options);
                    inStream.close();

                    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

                    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                    inStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);

                    CommonStaticClass.mImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStream, null, options);

                    ExifInterface exif = null;

                    try {
                        //File pictureFile = new File(imgDecodableString);
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
                            exif = new ExifInterface(inStream);
                            Log.d("exif", "sdk 24");
                        }
                        else {
                            exif = new ExifInterface(imageUri.getPath());
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    int orientation = ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL;

                    if (exif != null)
                        orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

                    switch (orientation) {
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                            CommonStaticClass.mImage = rotateBitmap(CommonStaticClass.mImage, 90);
                            break;
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                            CommonStaticClass.mImage = rotateBitmap(CommonStaticClass.mImage, 180);
                            break;

                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                            CommonStaticClass.mImage = rotateBitmap(CommonStaticClass.mImage, 270);
                            break;
                    }

                    inStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //Toast.makeText(this, "IO exception", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(this, SelectSuitActivity.this.getString(R.string.wrong_msg), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                //CommonStaticClass.mImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, SelectSuitActivity.this.getString(R.string.wrong_msg), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

And here is the logcat result when I pick image from camera:

```
    10-19 12:39:04.399 2912-2912/com.example.myapp I/ExifInterface_JNI: Corrupted image.
    10-19 12:39:04.414 2912-2912/com.example.myapp W/ExifInterface: Invalid image: ExifInterface got an unsupported image format file(ExifInterface supports JPEG and some RAW image formats only) or a corrupted JPEG file to ExifInterface.
    java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:270)
    at android.media.ExifInterface.getJpegAttributes(ExifInterface.java:1834)
    at android.media.ExifInterface.loadAttributes(ExifInterface.java:1475)
    at android.media.ExifInterface.<init>(ExifInterface.java:1174)
    at com.lostsym.founder.SelectSuitActivity.onActivityResult(SelectSuitActivity.java:621)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6932)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4085)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4132)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1533)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

It would be helpful if anyone can figure out what's wrong here. Thank you.

Comment: Your jpg files are corrupted. Or you use a not supported image format.

Comment: You use inStream after it has been used by BitmapFactory. That is not possible. Open the stream yet another time.

Comment: @greenapps Thank you very much. Your suggestion solves my problem.

Comment: @MohammadMazedulIslam can you post your answer?

Comment: @surhidamatya I don't have the exact code at this moment. But the idea is, you can not reuse input stream after it has been decoded by the BitmapFactory. I just declared a new InputStream when I needed it for the second time.

Comment: See also https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/3851 if you use `Glide` and don't use `ExifInterface` (the problem still has not been solved).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use inStream after it has been used by BitmapFactory. That is not possible. Open the stream yet another time.

Comment: Could you help elaborate the open stream another time implementation in source code. I am stuck and getting the idea but not the implementation

Answer (score 2):

**Invalid image: ExifInterface got an unsupported image format file(ExifInterface supports JPEG and some RAW image formats only) or a corrupted JPEG file to ExifInterface.**

This error showing in my app and might be problem of extension is not proper in Image URL. I have using the Glide library to load image and showing the error like **ExifInterface supports JPEG and some RAW image formats only**

After that I have cleared the cache and data from Application settings then it showing correct image but it showing the different log message as below

```
Load failed for http://myserverurl.com/web/image/product.template/7783/image_1920?unique=20201014051228 with size [146x156]
class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
There was 1 cause:
java.io.FileNotFoundException(https://myserverurl.com/web/image/product.template/7783/image_1920?unique=20201014051228)
 call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
  Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE
```

**Below Image URL using in Glide**
***https://myserverurl.com/web/image/product.template/7783/image_1920?unique=20201014051228***

**Note:** Above image url is reference purpose and not available in that server currently.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was getting this warning because of file path of screenshot, I have taken a screenshot of an app, and the complete path of that file was like this:

```
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Screenshots/Screenshot_2019-10-10-12-16-54-246_com.some_package_name.png
```

As you can see, **there is . between com and some_package_name**, because of this . I was getting this error.

Comment: how did you solve this?. I am fetching files from Mediastore